# vuejs3 + Firebase: error linking anonymous account with Twitter provider

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, vuejs3

#### What I want to happen:

When a new user visits my app, I want create an anonymous user that will store a code. This code is an invite reference as I want my app to be invite only. The user should then be able to chose signin with twitter (and others) and they will link so that in the future they can just login with those providers. I would like these providers to be the same as they will all need to access the invite code.

#### What is happening:

I have a new application. In the app, I am automatically signing in the user with an anonymous account... This is called in the `async mounted() in App.vue`:

```
if (!auth.currentUser) {
    try {
       const { user } = await signInAnonymously(auth);
       console.log("Logged In Anonymously.. user:", user);
       console.log("Anonymous User ID: ", user.uid);
    } catch (error) {
       console.error("Error signing in anonymously:", error);
    }
} else {
  console.log("User is already signed in:", auth.currentUser);
}
```

This works fine and created the anonymous user.

I then have a button that calls `await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);`.
This goes to twitter, I sign in and it redirects me to my app.

Back in my mounted function, I also have this code:

```
getRedirectResult(auth)
            .then(async (result) => {
                const credential = TwitterAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
                if (credential) {
                    console.log("credential got", credential);

                    try {
                        const twitterCredential = TwitterAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
                        await linkWithCredential(auth.currentUser, twitterCredential);
                        console.log("Anonymous account successfully linked with Twitter provider");
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error("Error linking anonymous account with Twitter provider:", error);
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
          },
```

Which is supposed to link the anonymous account and the twitter account together when the site returns form Twitter. However, it is not working. I get the following error:

> error linking anonymous account with Twitter provider: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/provider-already-linked).

When I check my firebase user dashboard I see the following:

[image]

So they are not linked.